# Question about filling empty heart on uiButton click

Tags: ios, swift

I'm displaying hearts every time I click a button. When clicked, empty hearts are filled, and when clicked again, the filled hearts are empty.

```
@IBOutlet weak var likeBtn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        likeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likeBtnClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
```

```
@objc func likeBtnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.isSelected == false {
                sender.tintColor = .white
                self.isSelected = true
            } else if self.isSelected == true {
                sender.tintColor = .red
                self.isSelected = false
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

How can I make the above heart fill in red when the button is clicked?

What I want is to create two situations with one image.

1.The heart is filled with red when clicking the button
2. Click again to clear the heart

Comment: You'll need to use two images, one with the heart unfilled, and one with it filled

Comment: Is it impossible with one image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your idea is to use single image, you need to use it as a glyph. Meaning you have to erase the color data and tint it with the right color each time. Now if you have a transparent fill and colored border that wouldn't work because you can't fill the UIImage with colors ignoring the original border color. You have few options here.

**Option 1** - Use two images

```swift
let deselectedImage = UIImage(named: "heart")
let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "heart-filled")
```

**Option 2** - Use one image and play with rendering mode

```swift
let deselectedImage = UIImage(named: "heart")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "heart")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
selectedImage.tintColor = .red
```

**Option 3** - Using layer border color & rendering moode

Same as option 2 but you will need a white heart image but in deselected mode you also set the border color for it.